# Can I create a kubernetes secret with the kubectl command using a .pfx certificate?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

command below gives an error: `error: flag key is required`

```
kubectl create secret tls k8-secret2 \
    -n ingress-tls-test1 \
    --cert ingress-tls-test1.pfx
```

I am able to create the secret using .crt and .key file:

```
kubectl create secret tls aks-ingress-tls \
    --namespace ingress-basic \
    --key aks-ingress-tls.key \
    --cert aks-ingress-tls.crt
```

Answer (score 8):

I needed to create a kube tls secret from .pfx file today
Credits to: https://adolfi.dev/blog/tls-kubernetes/

```bash
## you will enter the pfx PW on on the CMD/terminal
openssl pkcs12 -in pfx-filename.pfx -nocerts -out key-filename.key
openssl rsa -in key-filename.key -out key-filename-decrypted.key
openssl pkcs12 -in pfx-filename.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out crt-filename.crt  ##remove clcerts to get the full chain in your cert
kubectl create secret tls your-secret-name --cert crt-filename.crt --key key-filename-decrypted.key
```

Comment: fyi, this seems not to import the intermediate certs.

Comment: to have the entire chain remove: `clcerts`

Answer (score 5):

While creating k8s( up to `v1.19`) secret of `type: kubernetes.io/tls`, you **must** provide two keys; `tls.key` and `tls.crt`. If you use `kubectl` to create a secret, you can use `--cert` and `--key` flags to provide the values of those keys.

The public key certificate for `--cert` **must be .PEM encoded** (Base64-encoded DER format), and match the given private key for `--key`.

Since the `.pfx` certificate uses different encoding and stores all into a single encryptable file, you don't have separate certs and keys files to fulfil the requirements.

But you can create a secret of the type [Opaque](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#opaque-secrets) instead of [TLS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#tls-secrets).

```sh
$ kubectl create secret generic k8-secret2 --from-file=crt.pfx=./ingress-tls-test1.pfx
```

Comment: @notageek27 Accept the answer if it answered your query.

Comment: I tested with k8s 1.23.1, its not working, Tilo suggestion works for me.

Answer (score 2):

kubernetes v1.20 - you can create TLS secret imperatively:

**Syntax:**

```
kubectl create secret (command) (secret-name) (namespace) (cert) (key)
```

**Example:**

```
kubectl create secret tls webhook-server-tls --namespace webhook-demo --cert /root/keys/webhook-server-tls.crt --key /root/keys/webhook-server-tls.key
```